pydev warning / error when run under pycharm community
When the debugger break point is set and the debugger is run under pycharm community the follow error or warning appears in the debugging window.
pydev debugger: bytes arguments were passed to a new process creation function.  Breakpoints may not work correctly.
Breakpoints randomly work and then other times not including skipping functions calls when stepping.  Sometimes when debugging my entire system will lockup requiring a forced shutdown.
Env:
ubuntu 22.04 desktop
pycharm 2024.1.4
python 3.12 virtual env
Kivy 2.3.0
kivymd 2.0.1.dev0
Tried other versions of Python 3.10 (which is ubuntu's default).  Removed some kivymd widgets from my app.
The Debugger operated better with Python 3.10 but caused other problems with my app which is why I went to the latest version of Python.
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.
